# Using cmap for date contours with Cartopy

Tags: python, matplotlib, cartopy

I have a series of tif sea ice data (see 3 of them [here](https://github.com/vic1309/tif_seaice_data)) which I want to make contours where the sea ice concentration has a constant value of 50% (see figure attached).

[image].

Each red dashed line represents the aforementioned 50% value in April for every year between 1979 and 2020. Instead of all in one same color, I want to use a colormap, or something similar, where each line is depicted by one different color, which in turn is related to the year that it belongs to. Ultimately, using a colorbar, the reader can identify how these lines varied over the years. You can find the code for this figure [here](https://github.com/vic1309/tif_seaice_data).

Suggestions?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to extract time array from your dataset. For the sake of this example let's assume they are of type `datetime`.

```py
# necessary imports
from datetime import datetime
import matplotlib.colors as mcol
import matplotlib.cm as mcm
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


# some random dates
dts = [
    datetime(1991, 5, 6, 0, 0, 0),
    datetime(2000, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0),
    datetime(2015, 1, 15, 12, 34, 56),
    datetime(2020, 12, 3, 4, 5, 6),
]
```

You should then convert them into numbers:

```py
num_dt = [mdates.date2num(dt) for dt in dts]
```

If your dataset has dates as "pure" numbers, you can skip this step and just assign them to `num_dt`:

```py
num_dt = ds.time.values  # or something like that
```

Then you should create a `Normalize` object with a colormap of your choice:

```py
cmap = mcm.get_cmap("viridis")
cnorm = mcol.Normalize(num_dt[0], num_dt[-1])
```

Next, create a `ScalarMappable` using the colormap and normalisation from above:

```py
sm = mcm.ScalarMappable(norm=cnorm, cmap=cmap)
```

Finally, when you loop over time slices of your data, use the given time stamp to define colour:

```py
for time_stamp in my_times:
    num_time = mdates.date2num(time_stamp)  # or use the numeric value straight away, if time_stamp is a number
    color = sm.to_rgba(num_time)
    plt.contour(data_slice, colors=[color])
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Dear Denis. It worked perfectly at the time I posted this issue, but now something happened. I used to use sm to construct a colorbar, but now I get the following message:

TypeError: You must first set_array for mappable

Do you know what happened? It's absolutely the same dataset and code..

Comment: @VictorAguiar I've updated the code with `colors=` instead of `color=` at the last line, perhaps this was the problem? Otherwise, check if you're using the latest version of matplotlib. I've just tested this code on some random data and it still works.

Comment: The problem is actually when I try to plot the colorbar:

cb = fig.colorbar(sm, shrink=1, extend='both')

It is outside the for loop